# Follow me my dear friend

Tags: riddle, word, cipher, rhyme, poetry

```
01000101 01110110 01100101 01110010 01100100 01100001 01111001 00100000 01110111 01100101 00100000 01100011 01110010 01101111 01110011 01110011 00100000 01100101 01100001 01100011 01101000 00100000 01101111 01110100 01101000 01100101 01110010 01110011 00100000 01110000 01100001 01110100 01101000

01010011 01101111 01101101 01100101 01110100 01101001 01101101 01100101 01110011 00100000 01111001 01101111 01110101 00100000 01100110 01101111 01101100 01101100 01101111 01110111 00100000 01101101 01100101 00100000 01101001 01101110 00100000 01110111 01110010 01100001 01110100 01101000

01001001 01100110 00100000 01111001 01101111 01110101 00100000 01100100 01101111 00100000 01101110 01101111 01110100 00100000 01100110 01101111 01101100 01101100 01101111 01110111 00100000 01001001 00100000 01100001 01101101 00100000 01101110 01101111 01110100 00100000 01110100 01101000 01100101 01110010 01100101

01000110 01101001 01101110 01100100 01101001 01101110 01100111 00100000 01101101 01100101 00100000 01110111 01101001 01110100 01101000 01101111 01110101 01110100 00100000 01110010 01110101 01101100 01100101 01110011 00100000 01101001 01110011 00100000 01100101 01110110 01100101 01110010 00100000 01110011 01101111 00100000 01110010 01100001 01110010 01100101

01000101 01110011 01110000 01100101 01100011 01101001 01100001 01101100 01101100 01111001 00100000 01100100 01100101 01110110 01100101 01101100 01101111 01110000 01100101 01110010 01110011 00100000 01101100 01101001 01101011 01100101 00100000 01110100 01101111 00100000 01110101 01110011 01100101 00100000 01101101 01100101

01001001 01101110 00100000 01110100 01101000 01100101 01101001 01110010 00100000 01110111 01101111 01110010 01101011 00100000 01101111 01110010 00100000 01100011 01101111 01101110 01110110 01100101 01110010 01110011 01100001 01110100 01101001 01101111 01101110 00100000 01001001 00100000 01100001 01101101 00100000 01110100 01101000 01100101 00100000 01101011 01100101 01111001

01010111 01101000 01101111 00100000 01100001 01101101 00100000 01001001 00111111
```

> if(binary == text){amIUsed = true;}else{amIUsed = false;}

Answer (score 2):

First we

> convert the binary code into ASCII text,

which gives:

> Everday we cross each others path
>  Sometimes you follow me in wrath
>  If you do not follow I am not there
>  Finding me without rules is ever so rare
>  Especially developers like to use me
>  In their work or conversation I am the key
>  Who am I?

So I think the answer is

> CODE.

Line-by-line explanation:

> Line 1: many users of this site will see code every day.
>  Line 2: a warrior fighting in wrath might follow a code, or a member of an online community might follow a code of conduct so their wrath isn't damaging.
>  Line 3: not sure?
>  Line 4: code has rules, otherwise it's pretty much useless.
>  Line 5: developers use code a lot.
>  Line 6: they work with code and talk about it too.

Comment: Well done, you converted it to the right text. Sadly the final answer is incorrect.

Answer (score 2):

As noted by @Rand al'Thor in a previous answer, the first step is:

> To convert the binary code into ASCII text, which yields a riddle.

And then the answer might be

> Logical deduction/reasoning

Let's start with the title: 'Follow me my dear friend'

> Logic is often the key to solving riddles, and this is a riddle.

Then let's explain the hint:

> 'if(binary == text){amIUsed = true;}else{amIUsed = false;}' Since the binary (ASCII) did indeed correspond to text, this hint is indeed used! Now what is a conditional statement (which this hint is) if not the heart of logical deduction?

And now for the heart of the problem:

> Everday we cross each others path -> Logic is indeed used and seen everywhere on this site
>  Sometimes you follow me in wrath -> In can be frustratingly hard to find the correct reasoning when solving a puzzle
>  Finding me without rules is ever so rare -> A method of thinking is often necessary in order to build a logical solution
>  If you do not follow I am not there -> There is no logic in what you do if you do not apply the rules of logic (i.e. if you do not follow logic)
>  Especially developers like to use me -> A developer must apply logic when debugging code (simply changing parameters willy nilly until the problem is seamingly solved is likely to introduce new bugs)
>  In their work or conversation I am the key -> Developers work with software, which is logical by nature (for a certain definition of 'logical'), and they'll often discuss logic (for instance when discussing types)

Answer (score 0):

Given the ASCII conversion I think the answer is:

> A bug

Edit: I think my original answer was incorrect. I now think it is:

> A bug in a patch

My reasoning:

> Lines 1 & 2: Developers encounter bugs often, sometimes bugs persist causing anger, especially in patches.
>
> Line 3: No bug, no need for patching anything
>
> Line 4: Developers often have to patch code
>
> Line 5: Patches are usually the answers to fixing code

Comment: You should expand your answer to contain an explanation. Typically riddle answers explain why they are a good fit by explaining each line of the riddle

Comment: Nice try, but incorrect. Line 3 is meant more in rot13(vg qbrfa'g rkvfg vs lbh qba'g sbyybj vg juvpu vf abg gur pnfr jvgu n oht).